# How to share a computer between several remote users simultaneously?

Tags: remote-access

There is a highly specced computer (Intel based) we want to be used by several users, to run certain software (the software requires a lot of CPU and RAM, which is the reason they are not running it on their own computers but on this more powerful one). The software runs under Windows.

The users will do this remotely, from their own computer (running Windows). Often several users at the same time.

How to do this in the "best" way?

(I do have some ideas, but no actual field experience, so I'll keep them for myself)

Additional information:

- the software is of a GUI type (so batch processing is not really an option, although it may be done, but no experience there, the users are not techies)
- licensing for the software in question (the application) is not an issue, lets assume multiple users can use it without limitations

Comment: The " best" way depends on many things and not the least on what the software package supports and is used for. (Setting up a job scheduler and users submitting their jobs and getting their results sequentially in the order their jobs were submitted is different from supporting several concurrent interactive sessions) Licensing terms may also be important; when you'll be charged full price per seat for each additional  concurrent user that shares the system it might be better value to also invest in the corresponding dedicated hardware for each user, rather than sharing resources between them

Comment: add some relevant data to the question

Answer (score 2):

https://aws.amazon.com/hpc/dcv/

https://download.nice-dcv.com/

- install nice-dcv server on your windows *server*
- install nice-dcv client on all the clients
- the nice-dcv server is where it's licensed
- I believe it comes with a demo license where you can at least test drive one remote connection to get an understanding
- i use it where the server is RHEL7 and the clients are win10, it works well; I've never used nice-dcv between windows and windows.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the operating system you might be able to [setup the application as a RemoteApp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-create-collection) and publish it for the users.  It kinda works like a microsoft version of citrix.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a stupid answer, but plain RDP itself would likely work well if your graphical requirements weren't super demanding ([step-by-step installing rds](https://msfreaks.wordpress.com/2018/10/06/step-by-step-windows-2019-remote-desktop-services-using-the-gui/)). Assuming at least you're using windows Server. Using Windows 10 would be a bit of a problem, VNC could work, but I wouldn't recommend.